# Java Interface parameter

Tags: java, class, methods, arraylist, interface

I'm having trouble understanding this interface problem. I'm supposed to create a Word class with methods getFirst() to return the first character, getLast() to return the last character, getSequence() to return an arraylist of all the characters, and getPosition() should return the int representing the Word's position in the sentence.

I get an error message on the "OrderedThing" parameter (OrderedThing cannot be resolved to a type) - what do I do in the Word class that will solve this? I'm confused on what "OrderedThing" is (type? parameter?)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public interface SequentiallyOrdered {

    public OrderedThing getFirst();
    public OrderedThing getLast();
    public ArrayList<OrderedThing> getSequence();

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `OrderedThing` is a class that is being used as a return type for your abstract methods. Can you post your `Word` class?

Comment: What is `OrderedThing`, and why aren't you returning `Character`? Is your interface supposed to be generic?

Comment: thanks for the clarification, excuse my novice mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have at least the following:

**OrderedThing.java**:

```
public class OrderedThing {

}
```

**SequentiallyOrdered.java**:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public interface SequentiallyOrdered {
        public OrderedThing getFirst();
        public OrderedThing getLast();
        public ArrayList<OrderedThing> getSequence();   
}
```

**Word.java**:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Word implements SequentiallyOrdered {

    @Override
    public OrderedThing getFirst() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public OrderedThing getLast() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<OrderedThing> getSequence() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Make sure to implement the **SequentiallyOrdered** interface in your class and add the unimplemented methods then do your logic inside those methods.

Answer (score 1):

You have to import the class OrderedThing. If you are using eclipse, `Ctrl + Shift + O`

Comment: thanks for the clarification, excuse my novice mistake!